# MPI Broadcast on subset of MPI_COMM_WORLD results in deadlock

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I don't get why the program deadlocks on `rank=3` in first iteration. (Possibly different for you).

I want to do some batch processing and if the batch size isn't a multiply of processes I have to handle that case.

I would expect following program flow:

1. sign up all processes to `activ_com`
2. `rank=1` exits: disconnects from `activ_com`, waits on `MPI_Finalize`
3. first iteration: `rank=0` sends data, `rank=2,3` receive data
4. `rank=3` exits: disconnects form `active_com`, waits on 'MPI_Finalize`, in real life possible that 5. happens before discconect
5. second iteration: `rank=0` sends data, `rank=2` receive data
6. `rank=0,1` exits

It suggest that I didn't understood something fundamentally but I can't figure it out, what is happening and why here.

I tried to study the docs [[3]](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.0/mpi40-report.pdf) as suggested in the solution of [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299279/mpi-bcast-and-the-number-of-processes). Find below and MRE below that shows my case.

As you can see I try to use a sub communicator to Bcast only on the active processes.
The deadlock apears in step (3), in the first iteration.

I already got an explanation how to handle such case with `MPI_Scatterv`and `MPI_Gatherv`. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209911/better-way-than-loop-over-mpi-send-mpi-recv-if-data-not-divisable-my-comm-size)
But I think there should be another possibility than using `MPI_Scatterv` instead of `MPI_Bcast`

Another possible solution could be the use of `Session Model`, but I think it is crucial to understand what is happening here.

Thank you very much for your help and time.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 32

static int world_size;

MPI_Comm activ_com;
#define COM_ACTIVE_TAG 1

static void signoff(int rank)
{
        printf("Registered for Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", rank, world_size);
        /* tested splitting for signoff */        
        //MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNDEFINED, rank, &activ_com);
        if (rank != 0) {
                int process = 0;
                MPI_Status status;
                MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE,MPI_ANY_TAG, activ_com, &process, &status);
                if (process)
                        printf("Communication still pending from %d on %d\n", status.MPI_SOURCE, rank);
        }
                MPI_Comm_disconnect(&activ_com);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);      // initialize MPI environment
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
        int world_rank;
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

        //MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, COM_ACTIVE_TAG, world_rank, &activ_com);
        MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &activ_com);

        int workers[world_size];
        for (int i = 0; i < world_size; ++i)
                workers[i] = true;
        
        long dummy[N];
        time_t t;
        if (world_rank == 0)
                srand(3);
        if (world_rank == 2)
                srand(7);
        if (world_rank == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                        dummy[i] = i;
        }
        if (world_rank == 1) {
                
                //printf("Registered for Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", world_rank, world_size);
                signoff(world_rank);
                MPI_Finalize();
                printf("Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", world_rank, world_size);
                return 0;
        }

        for(int i = world_rank; i < 7; i+=world_size) {
                int wait = 0;

                /* use different wait times for testing */
                if (world_rank != 3)
                        wait = rand() % 10;
                
                printf("Bcast: %d/%d, i=%d, waittime=%d\n", world_rank, world_size, i, wait);
                sleep(wait);
                
                /* rank=3 is hanging here in the first iteration */              
                MPI_Bcast(&dummy, N, MPI_LONG, 0, activ_com);
                
                printf("Bcast: %d/%d, i=%d, processed\n", world_rank, world_size, i);
        }

        /* keep rank alive for testing */
        if (world_rank == 3)
                sleep(5);


        signoff(world_rank);
        MPI_Comm_free(&activ_com);
        MPI_Finalize();
        printf("Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", world_rank, world_size);
        return 0;
}
```

using:

```
$ mpirun --version
mpirun (Open MPI) 4.1.2

$ mpicc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0
```

[1] [Better way than loop over MPI_Send/MPI_Recv if data not divisable my COMM_SIZE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209911/better-way-than-loop-over-mpi-send-mpi-recv-if-data-not-divisable-my-comm-size)

[2] [MPI Bcast and the number of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299279/mpi-bcast-and-the-number-of-processes)

[3] https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.0/mpi40-report.pdf

Comment: A collective subroutine must be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you, this is why I though I could setup a ***subset*** (via disconnecting the others, ***activ_com***). So I suspect the collective subroutine is invoked by all the ranks of the communicator (***activ_com***).

Comment: or differently stated. I don't understand why `rank=3` is blocking in first iteration. I see your point if you refer to the second iteration (I believe).
`MPI_Bcast` on `rank=0` should only proceed if it copied data to all receive buffers, which again should let proceed `rank=2,3`. At least this is my understanding, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: The right approach is to create a new communicator with all ranks but 3, and then MPI_Bcast on this communicator.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet 
OK, but how do I create the correct communicator?
The only way I can think of (besides what I already show here) is to keep an array of ranks I want to exclude. Using that to creating a group and communicator with that information.
Is this what you mean?

Comment: What you want is to use MPI_Comm_split(). Forget about MPI_Comm_disconnect, that is fairly advanced and seldom used functionality that is absolutely not appropriate here.

Comment: @janneb thank you, I played a bit more with `MPI_Comm_split`, but I trouble to understand how to use it correctly in this case.
What I tried is to call split with `MPI_UNDEFINED` in the `signoff` function.
After the loop the signoff function is calls only `if (world_rank > (max_iteration % world_size)`, within the loop i call split with an color=1.
It hangs on the second iteration. I can share my code if you like, if so, should I just append it to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @janneb and @GillesGouaillardet their hints let me play around with the right things it seems.

The following example shows how (I think) to use `MPI_Comm_split` correctly to create different communicators to handle early exits of the processes.

The **key idea** here is to create communicators upfront the loop, instead of doing it in the loop.

We create 2 communicators: `activ_com` which includes all processes that possible loop.
`loop_com` is again an subset of `activ_com` of processes for the last iteration

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 32

static int world_size;

MPI_Comm activ_com;
#define COM_ACTIVE 1
#define COM_LOOP 2

static void signoff(int rank)
{
    printf("Registered for Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", rank, world_size);
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNDEFINED, rank, &activ_com);
    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", rank, world_size);
 }

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);      // initialize MPI environment
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    int workers[world_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < world_size; ++i)
            workers[i] = true;
    
    long dummy[N];
    time_t t;
    if (world_rank == 0)
            srand(3);
    if (world_rank == 2)
            srand(7);
    if (world_rank == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                    dummy[i] = i;
    }
    if (world_rank == 1) {
            signoff(world_rank);
            return 0;
    }
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, COM_ACTIVE, world_rank, &activ_com);

    const int nmax = 7;
    MPI_Comm loop_com;
    if (world_rank > (nmax % world_size)) {
            MPI_Comm_split(activ_com, MPI_UNDEFINED, world_rank, &loop_com);
    } else {
            MPI_Comm_split(activ_com, COM_LOOP, world_rank, &loop_com);
    }
    for(int i = world_rank; i < nmax; i+=world_size) {
            int wait = 0;

            /* use different wait times for testing */
            if (world_rank != 3)
                    wait = rand() % 10;
            
            printf("Bcast: %d/%d, i=%d, waittime=%d\n", world_rank, world_size, i, wait);
            sleep(wait);
            
            MPI_Bcast(&dummy, N, MPI_LONG, 0, (i > (nmax%world_size))?loop_com:activ_com);

            printf("Bcast: %d/%d, i=%d, processed\n", world_rank, world_size, i);
    }

    if (world_rank == 3)
            sleep(5);

    MPI_Comm_free(&activ_com);
    MPI_Comm_free(&loop_com);
    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("Signoff: rank %d out of %d processors\n", world_rank, world_size);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).